# hadoop MaxTemperature example is not working on VMware with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

getting error on terminal  when i run comand 
 /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar climat.jar MaxTemperature sample.txt /out

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problems:     Job cannot be resolved to a type    Job cannot be resolved
> to a type     FileInputFormat cannot be resolved  Path cannot be resolved
> to a type     FileOutputFormat cannot be resolved     Path cannot be
> resolved to a type    Text cannot be resolved to a type   IntWritable
> cannot be resolved to a type
> 
>   at MaxTemperature.main(MaxTemperature.java:15)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar for compiling your map reduce code  if you  are using 1.x.

hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar and hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar if you are using  hadoop 2.x for writing map reduce code .

For detail please follow steps from below wiki run a word count map reduce code and follow the same for your climate jar  :
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html